# Question on calculating power for a prediction based study

Tags: statistical-power

I've calculated required power for a study in the past but I've come upon a scenario that I can't figure out quite how to do it. Pretty much I have a procedure that results in a particular complication 15% of the time. My study uses an imaging intervention on all study participants that we believe can predict the occurance of that complication >= 50% of the time. How would I go about calculating the required power/patients needed for a study like this?

Thank you.

Comment: It it correct to assume that the complication will not happen anymore if you are able to predict it based on imaging?

Comment: The purpose of the study is use the imaging to classify a patient into Group 1 or Group 2 with the hypothesis that a certain complication will occur more commonly in Group 2 when compared with Group 1.

Comment: So the imaging does not help to minimize the complication risk in some way?

Comment: Not in the context of the current study. We are just trying to predict complications with it. In the future, if we show we can indeed predict, measures could be taken to prevent the complication but that would be a next step kinda thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are not worried about false positives. In that case the patients that do not have the complication are not of interest to you. You want to design the study to claim a certain degree of sensitivity.

There may be a way to calculate this directly, but since no one has answered you yet I will show my approach. I calculated the p-values for a one sided proportion test using the R prop.test() function and null hypothesis that % correct <0.5. **This approach ignores all the patients who did not have complications. It gives the number of patients with complications that you will need.**

This was done for samples sizes in the sequence of 10 to 100 by 1, and for % correct from .01 to 1 by .01. Then from these results I found the minimum % correct that yielded p<0.05 for each sample size.

The upper chart shows the relationship between "significant" % corrects vs sample size. While the lower shows power functions for a few example sample sizes. For the latter, the horizontal line corresponds to p=.05.

If n=10 then the minimum observed % correct that will allow you to "reject" (at p<0.05) the hypothesis that your method is will detect less than half the patients with complications is 76.1%. Even for n=100 (remember this is 100 patients **with complications**), you will need to observe at least a 58.3% success rate to claim "significance".

If you want to calculate the total number of patients to enroll you need to multiply the sample sizes by 1/0.15 which is ~7.

I am fairly confident about this approach but not 100%, so hopefully someone will check it.

[image]

**R code:**

```
n<-seq(10,100,by=1) # sample sizes to check
perc.correct<-seq(.001,1,by=.001) # observed percent correct to check

alpha<-0.05 # "Significance" Cutoff

out=matrix(nrow=length(n)*length(perc.correct),ncol=3)
cnt=1
for(i in n){
  for(j in perc.correct){
    p<-prop.test(j*i,i, p=.5, alternative="g", correct=F)$p.value
    out[cnt,]<-cbind(i,100*j,p)
    cnt<-cnt+1
  }
}


# get lowest % correct that yielded p<0.05 for each sample size
out2=matrix(nrow=length(n),ncol=2)
cnt<-1
for(n2 in n){
  min.perc<-head(out[which(out[,1]==n2 & out[,3]<alpha),2],1)
  out2[cnt,]<-cbind(n2,min.perc)
  cnt<-cnt+1
}


# plots
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,5), ncol=2, nrow=3, byrow=T))
plot(out2, xlab="Sample Size", ylab="% Correct",
     main=c("% Correct to Reject Hypothesis Success <50%",paste("alpha=",alpha))
)

for(n2 in c(10,30,60,100)){
  min.perc<-head(out[which(out[,1]==n2 & out[,3]<alpha),2],1)
  plot(out[which(out[,1]==n2),2],out[which(out[,1]==n2),3], 
       xlab="% Correct", ylab="P-Value", 
       main=c(paste("n=",n2),paste("Min % Correct for p<", alpha,"=",min.perc))
  )
  abline(h=alpha)
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a different perspective. In this case we take the theory of % correct prediction of complications >50% as the null hypothesis. So using the significance testing logic we would choose to study the imaging technique more if it is not significant, but not use it if the result is significant. Here we are attempting to disprove the research hypothesis rather than the opposite as was done above (although the original way using reverse logic is the common approach for some strange reason).

[image]

**R code 2 (lines with minor changes marked with "#*" at the end):**

```
n<-seq(10,100,by=1) # sample sizes to check
perc.correct<-seq(.001,1,by=.001) # observed percent correct to check

alpha<-0.05 # "Significance" Cutoff

out=matrix(nrow=length(n)*length(perc.correct),ncol=3)
cnt=1
for(i in n){
  for(j in perc.correct){
    p<-prop.test(j*i,i, p=.5, alternative="l", correct=F)$p.value #*
    out[cnt,]<-cbind(i,100*j,p)
    cnt<-cnt+1
  }
}


# get highest % correct that yielded p<0.05 for each sample size
out2=matrix(nrow=length(n),ncol=2)
cnt<-1
for(n2 in n){
  max.perc<-tail(out[which(out[,1]==n2 & out[,3]<alpha),2],1) #*
  out2[cnt,]<-cbind(n2,max.perc) #*
  cnt<-cnt+1
}


# plots
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,5), ncol=2, nrow=3, byrow=T))
plot(out2, xlab="Sample Size", ylab="% Correct",
     main=c("% Correct to Reject Hypothesis Success >50%",paste("alpha=",alpha))
)

for(n2 in c(10,30,60,100)){
  max.perc<-tail(out[which(out[,1]==n2 & out[,3]<alpha),2],1) #*
  plot(out[which(out[,1]==n2),2],out[which(out[,1]==n2),3], 
       xlab="% Correct", ylab="P-Value", 
       main=c(paste("n=",n2),paste("Max % Correct for p<", alpha,"=",max.perc)) #*
  )
  abline(h=alpha)
}
```

Comment: This suggestion is quite similar to what I thought of. But the fact that there is no control group and most probably no blinding made me frawn... the study will perform better with increasing proportion of complication...

Comment: @Michael Mayer What do you mean by "perform better"? As far as I can tell with my method the % of complications is irrelevant except for the total patients needed to enroll. They will know the % at the end and then see how many of those were predicted correctly. If you mean increased sample size (here being the percent with complications) means more likely to "get significance", then yea but the one sided p value is much more reasonable than the two sided. I was actually thinking of using the prediction of >=50% success as null hypothesis but thought it would be confusing due to convention.

Comment: Good point, but still blinding is essential (and might even be possible). What made me also worried: If you put everyone in the group of which you think it predicts complication, then your imaging technique even predicts 100% of all complications. (This does not stick to your design but still answers the original question)

Comment: @MichaelMayer I think they know for a fact who has complications or not but only after the imaging technique is used. The imaging is not measuring the "complications". Imagine it is complications from some surgery. The timecourse is Imaging/Prediction -> Surgery -> Yes/No complication.

Comment: @MichaelMayer My guess is this prediction will be used to decide whether or not to use an alternative method (say a different surgery) that may be always safer but more expensive. So it would always be better to use the alternative if not for the cost, to reduce cost they will only use the alternative if they get a positive prediction of complications. I think a control group is not necessary here. The question is not clear enough to know for sure though.

Comment: The assessment of complications is not always perfectly objective. Furthermore, 'my' stupid predictor that everyone will get the complication, will perform better than imaging because false positives are ignored. I will be able to catch every single complication.

Comment: @MichaelMayer I see what you mean by perform better now. My definition is different (and based on my assumptions noted above), performance is probably being determined by cost-benefit. It is not good performance to predict complications if they will not occur. But the cost is not so high relative to the benefit that some false positives (low specificity) would be a problem. Wit this definition the use of the imaging to predict may still perform better than the "stupid predictor". I think we need to know more about the problem to say.

Comment: @Flask Thank you very much for the great explanation. We are consulting with a statistician at our institution as well so we will review this with him/her.